# VS Code shortcut keys to increase and decrease indentation width

Tags: visual-studio-code, key-bindings

Consider the following actions in a tab indented file.

[image]

Is it possible to create a keybinding that progressively increases/decreases the tab size?

Searching for `indent` in the keybindings window (`Ctrl K, Ctrl S`) gives the following options to which some keybinding can be attached to.

[image]

Is some sort of a multi-command needed to accomplish this via keybindings?

Comment: Probably the _quickest_ way to accomplish this is to set the Indent using Spaces/Tabs settings to some keybinding, and then use the arrows keys to select the number of spaces/tabs you want and perform a format on the file.  Sounds like a lot, but you could actually perform these actions is like 5 seconds or less if you are speedy.

Answer (score 0):

The title of your question and the question itself is not the same.
In VSCode you can use Tab and Shift+Tab to decrease/increase the indentation of a given line. -- this answers your title (for anyone else trying to look for this).

Regarding shortcuts to tab size change your only option is to use an extension such as altbdoor's change tab size: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=altbdoor.change-tab-size